Tableau: Can I have a button that the user can press to choose the color palette of a visual (map)
I am fairly new to Tableau.
I have a map. I wonder if I can have a button or something that a user can interact to change the colour palette of the legend.
This is useful for example, for color-blind people to choose a palette more adapted to their problem.
Any suggestion?

As a preface here is an article on switching color palletes via parameters that I believe is the best way to go about what you are trying to accomplish.
Couple of solutions though:
Custom Calculated Field + Parameters
Create a calculated field with a case statement for each "color palette" you want. When a parameter is selected it returns the same data but you will just map the colors in the marks pane differently for each respective palette. link in the preface.
Sheet Swaps
Simply create all the permutations of the map colors you want as separate sheets and swap them in as needed. Many guides on how to do this here is one for reference.
Parameter Actions
Similar to sheet swaps, parameter actions work more or less in the same way but you can set them up so the uses clicks a "button" rather than a drop down. I usually shy away from this as it messes with screen readers sometimes. In any case, check out the documentation here.
